# Seeking article on network analysis, connectivity analysis, and proximity related to routes and influence of stations?

Tags: postgis, network, spatial-analysis, gvsig

Unfortunately, I lost a document I had found on the internet, and I do not remember the title.  The article was like a guide or recipe and it was in PDF format, and it was related to network analysis, connectivity analysis and proximity.
one of the images is similar to this: [example 1](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-PgnlMJuXXsc/WntaUkjg8TI/AAAAAAAABfs/N_lSzajSdQgHVAxTcJJ_KVBPVvf0X8LVwCLcBGAs/s400/redes%2Bgvsig%2Bconnectivity.JPG) or this [example 2](http://personales.upv.es/jpalomav/cursos/gvsig/files/img_547.jpg)

But it was complete for the different police or fire stations, I do not remember it.
The author analyzed the distances, routes, and areas of influence of the police stations.the map represents the vias in different colors, which correspond to the area of influence of the stations.

It was made in PostGIS

Can you help me to find that document?

It is an article with a few pages.

Answer (score 1):

We have found it after
8 hours of uninterrupted search of images, PDF, forums, gscholar....

This is: [GST 102: Spatial Analysis](https://foss4geo.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/gst_102_lab_6_vector_data_analysis_network_analysis.pdf)

This site did not know him and they have good exercises to adapt and do in  software libre [GIS Training](https://www.cdc.gov/dhdsp/maps/gisx/training/index.html)
and without a doubt the information of grass [grass](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WxGUI_Vector_Network_Analysis_Tool)

Answer (score 1):

if you finally want to use gvSIG as it was shown at the screenshots here you can find more information about network extension in gvSIG Desktop:

- Manuals:

http://downloads.gvsig.org/download/web.save/projects/gvsig-desktop/docs/user/ext/redes/network-analisys-0-1-0/gvsig_allFreemindTocContentsOnOnePage36a9.html?urlpath=http://www.gvsig.org/web/projects/gvsig-desktop/docs/user/ext/redes/network-analisys-0-1-0/network-analisys-0-1-0/gvsig_freemind_toc_view&content=Redes

http://personales.upv.es/jpalomav/cursos/gvsig/gvsig_19.html?t692.html

- Videos:

http://downloads.gvsig.org/download/web.save/projects/gvsig-desktop/tour/videos/network.html

You have to take into account that network extension is available for gvSIG 1.x, it hasn't been migrated to gvSIG 2.x yet, but you can have both versions installed on your computer and load files from one to the other one.

As gvSIG 1.12 was developed some time ago you need to follow specific steps to install it on the latest operating systems. If you have any problem installing gvSIG 1.12 with network extension you can send the problem to the mailing list:
http://listserv.gva.es/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/gvsig_internacional

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know the exact document you're referring to.

It looks like you're after something similar to the output from GRASS' [v.net.iso](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.net.iso.html) algorithm. This categorises road segments according to the nearest point of interest (school, fire station etc). If you search Google images for that you may stumble across something similar.

The filenames of the screenshots suggests it was done with [gvSIG](http://www.gvsig.com/en), that might be a starting point. I think networking is available as an add-on/plugin for that. I've tagged your question with that in case it helps.